# Azure service bus not listing in deployment of resource group

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, azureportal

I have created a service bus and deployed it to the resource group, the service bus was deleted from deployment and I am unable to add it back.

[image]

As you can there are 2 Succeeded the one highlighted is missing, how do I add it back from the azure portal?

PS: i am new to Azure learning as i go

Answer (score 0):

go to subcription and select deployments and redeploy the template.